# Opening a file in Ruby - unknown regexp options - Prgra ERROR?

Tags: ruby, regex, error-handling

I am trying to open a file and store the contents as useable input for my methods in a separate file. Specifically, I have one file "test_int_file.rb", which simply has one integer on each line. I would like to use each integer as input into my method.

I have attempted to open this file using this command in the same file where my methods are stored: 
    File.open("/Desktop/Programs/test_int_file.rb")

My plan was then to use something like the following to get each line as a separate integer input (stored in an array) that I can pass to my method:

```
file_arr = []
File.open("/Desktop/Programs/test_int_file.rb").each_line do |line|
file_arr << line.to_i
end
```

So Two Main Questions HERE:

1) When I attempt the File.open("/Desktop/Programs/test_int_file.rb") on my Mac, I get this error in my terminal:
    unknown regexp options - Prgra
What am I doing wrong in opening this file?

2) Will the block of code above work to get my input file of integers into an array of integers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that's the code which is generating that regexp options error? You may be missing the quotes around the file name in your real code which is causing that error.

Comment: Post the full error please

Comment: @Dogbert, I copy and pasted the code above from the file I'm running. That's all of the code. I even shortened it so that the entire file (called open_file.rb) only has this line of code: `File.open("/Desktop/Programs/test_int_file.rb") ` The output when I run ruby open_file.rb in my terminal is just 'unknown regexp options- Prgra'. Maybe I'm not understanding still...? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AntarrByrd the entire error is just `open_file.rb:2: unknown regexp options - Prgra`. Thanks!

Comment: @Kelsey I'm 100% sure that error is because the path is being parsed as a regex for some reason.